# One Web Page Doesn't Show Up and With The Error - The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared

Tags: php, twig

I've a project that uses `Twig Template` engine and every page of the project was working perfectly. Now suddenly from today, one of the pages doesn't show and got this - **The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared.** and here is the link - [Website Link](http://fagroupintl.com/financial-consultants/)
. The page contains the following code and also with the required tags (Even though I've tried to do some modification but didn't work):

```
{% extends "fafc.base.html.twig" %}

{% set title = "First Aid Financial Consultants" %}

{% block title %} {{ title }} {% endblock %}

  {% block head %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <link href="/assets/css/fadeSlider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
{% endblock %}



{% block sliderarea %}
  <section>

    <!-- New Slider-->
    <div class='csslider1 autoplay '>
      <input name="cs_anchor1" id='cs_slide1_0' type="radio" class='cs_anchor slide' >
      <input name="cs_anchor1" id='cs_slide1_1' type="radio" class='cs_anchor slide' >
      <input name="cs_anchor1" id='cs_slide1_2' type="radio" class='cs_anchor slide' >
      <input name="cs_anchor1" id='cs_slide1_3' type="radio" class='cs_anchor slide' >
      <input name="cs_anchor1" id='cs_play1' type="radio" class='cs_anchor' checked>
      <input name="cs_anchor1" id='cs_pause1_0' type="radio" class='cs_anchor pause'>
      <input name="cs_anchor1" id='cs_pause1_1' type="radio" class='cs_anchor pause'>
      <input name="cs_anchor1" id='cs_pause1_2' type="radio" class='cs_anchor pause'>
      <input name="cs_anchor1" id='cs_pause1_3' type="radio" class='cs_anchor pause'>
      <ul>
        <li class="cs_skeleton"><img src="/assets/images/sliders/fafc/bright-future-loans.jpg" style="width: 100%;"></li>
         <li class='num0 img slide'><img src='/assets/images/sliders/fafc/bright-future-loans.jpg'/></li>
        <li class='num1 img slide'> <img src='/assets/images/sliders/fafc/credit-apply-now.jpg'/></li>
        <li class='num2 img slide'> <img src='/assets/images/sliders/fafc/fafc-driven-success.jpg'/></li>
        <li class='num3 img slide'> <img src='/assets/images/sliders/fafc/refer-earn.jpg'/></li>
      </ul><div class="cs_engine"></div>

      <div class='cs_bullets'>
             <label class='num0' for='cs_slide1_0'> <span class='cs_point'></span>
        <span class='cs_thumb'><img src='/assets/images/sliders/fafc/thumbnail/bright-future-loans.jpg' /></span></label>
        <label class='num1' for='cs_slide1_1'> <span class='cs_point'></span>
          <span class='cs_thumb'><img src='/assets/images/sliders/fafc/thumbnail/credit-apply-now.jpg'/></span></label>
        <label class='num2' for='cs_slide1_2'> <span class='cs_point'></span>
        <span class='cs_thumb'><img src='/assets/images/sliders/fafc/thumbnail/fafc-driven-success.jpg'/></span></label>
        <label class='num3' for='cs_slide1_3'> <span class='cs_point'></span>
          <span class='cs_thumb'><img src='/assets/images/sliders/fafc/thumbnail/refer-earn.jpg'/></span></label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--
    <div class="banner bann1">
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="/assets/images/sliders/fafc/bright-future-loans.jpg" /></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="/assets/images/sliders/fafc/credit-apply-now.jpg" /></a>
          </li>
                <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="/assets/images/sliders/fafc/fafc-driven-success.jpg" /></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/refer-and-earn/"><img src="/assets/images/sliders/fafc/refer-earn.jpg" /></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  -->
  </section>
{% endblock %}

{% block gridarea %}
  {{ parent() }}  
{% endblock %}

{% block grid %}
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Your <span>Financial Health</span> Is Our <span>First Priority</span>.</a></li>
    <li><a href="/blog/infographics/"><img src="/assets/images/grid-tiles/infographics.jpg" alt="Store" title="View Infographics" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="/assets/images/grid-tiles/fafc/img1.jpg" alt="" title=""/></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="/assets/images/grid-tiles/fafc/img3.jpg" alt="" title=""/></a></li>
    <li><a href="/blog/articles/"><img src="/assets/images/grid-tiles/articles.jpg" alt="Latest Articles" title="Latest Articles"/></a></li>
    <li><a href="/blog/resources/"><img src="/assets/images/grid-tiles/resources.jpg" alt="Resources" title="Download Resources" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="/assets/images/grid-tiles/fafc/img2.jpg" alt="" title=""/></a></li>
    <li><a href="/blog/videos/"><img src="/assets/images/grid-tiles/videos.jpg" alt="Videos" title="Watch Videos"/></a></li>

  </ul>
{% endblock %}

{% block verticlemenu %}
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/{{ company_url }}/personal-loans">Personal Loans</a></li>
    <li><a href="/{{ company_url }}/business-loans">Business Loans</a></li>
    <li><a href="/{{ company_url }}/finance-partnership">Finance &amp; Partnership</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Chat With Us</a></li>
  </ul>
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
<section>
  <div class="span1 section-border"></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="fafclist">
      <ul>
        <li> <img src="/assets/images/dollar-icon.png" alt=""/>
          <h3>Payday Express</h3>
          <p>Get access to funds at the best interest rate with no guarantor required.</p>
          <div class="button-left text-align" > <a href="/{{ company_url }}/personal-loans/#payday-express" class="buttontn bttonfafc">CLICK HERE</a> </div>
        </li>
        <li><img src="/assets/images/home-icon.png" alt="Home" />
          <h3>Signature Executive</h3>
          <p>Designed for our loyal clients. Fantastic offers at floor rates. Become a member today.</p>
          <div class="button-left text-align" > <a href="/{{ company_url }}/personal-loans/#signature-executive" class="buttontn bttonfafc">CLICK HERE</a> </div>
        </li>
        <li> <img src="/assets/images/currency-icon.png" alt="Currency" />
          <h3>Premium Advantage</h3>
          <p>Take Control of your future by accessing our regular loan facility. </p>
          <div class="button-left text-align" > <a href="/{{ company_url }}/personal-loans/#premium-advantage" class="buttontn bttonfafc">CLICK HERE</a> </div>
        </li>
        <li> <img src="/assets/images/handshakesmall-icon.png" alt=""/>
          <h3>Apply Today</h3>
          <p>Take the opportunity. The time is now!!!<br/><br/></p>
          <div class="button-left text-align" > <a href="/{{ company_url }}/apply" class="buttontn bttonfafc">CLICK HERE</a> </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="dashed-border">
  <div class="wrapper"> 
    <!-- Container1-->
    <div class="hb-contbtgd pb mrgn-bttm">
      <aside class="half-width fafc">
        <h2>Finance and Partnership</h2>
        <div class="row">
         <!-- <div class="image"> <img src="/assets/images/epaydayexpress-icon.png" alt="" /></div>-->
          <div class="cntbox">Do you have a great idea but little or no funding to realize that dream? Let us assist you with the financial planning needed to get you on your way to success.  Come in and speak with one of our expert advisors today.<br>
            <a href="/{{ company_url }}/finance-partnership">Read more</a> </div>
        </div>
      </aside>
      <aside class="half-width fafc">
        <h2>Lease Financing</h2>
        <div class="row">
          <!--<div class="image"><img src="/assets/images/signature.png" alt="Signature"></div>-->
          <div class="cntbox">Do you need capital or machinery for your small business, but don’t know where to turn?  Let us purchase it for you. At First Aid Financials, your future is bright. Our payment terms are flexible and our rates are incomparable. <br>
            <a href="/{{ company_url }}/finance-partnership#lease-financing">Read more</a> </div>
        </div>
      </aside>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="mrtb">
  <div class="wrapper"> 
    <!-- Container-->
    <div class="wrapper listing-box fafclib">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="fafc">
            <h2>First Aid Financial Consultants</h2>
          </div>
          <p>Valid ID and TRN<br/><br/></p>
          <p>Last 3 payslips or job letter<br/><br/></p>
          <p>Recent Proof of Address<br/><br/></p>
          <a class="btn" href="/{{ company_url }}/apply">Apply Now</a>
          <div class="img"><img width="92" height="98" src="/assets/images/btn-arrow.png"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="red-gredential">
          <div class="heading1">
            <h2>Check out our same day loan</h2>
          </div>
          <p>Available within 24 hours<br/><br/></p>
          <p>No guarantor needed<br/><br/></p>
          <p>Convenient Online Application<br/><br/></p>
          <div class="img"><img width="92" height="98" src="/assets/images/white-arrow01.png"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="waitfor"> <img src="/assets/images/what-you-are-banner.jpg" alt="What you are waiting for"/></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

{% endblock %}
```

This page inherits few things from other pages and checked if the page contains the appropriate meta tags. The following were included:

```
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
```

I am not sure what kind of error is this and any idea to resolve would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Make sure all your files are `UTF-8`as well

Comment: I've already done that @DarkBee. Is there anything else that I require to do?

Comment: The page is returning a `500`-error, did you already check your error logs? Perhaps there is more to be found in there